# PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY error occuring while calling stored procedure in zf2

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, zend-framework2

when calling a stored procedure in zend framework 2 , it throwing an error message, how can i solve this issue ,

```
$dbAdapter = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $results = $dbAdapter->query("CALL PROCEDURE_NAME('PARAM1')");
    $DataSource = $results->execute();
    $Statement = $DataSource->getResource();
    $Result = $Statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

the above code is using to get stored procedure information

getting below error

Statement could not be executed (HY000 - 2014 - Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.)

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php and it will give you the information about your error.

Comment: where i can add MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY above code?

Comment: Solved my problem  , i just put closeCursor after fetching result

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem , i just put closeCursor after fetching result

```
$dbAdapter = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$results = $dbAdapter->query("CALL PROCEDURE_NAME('PARAM1')");
$DataSource = $results->execute();
$Statement = $DataSource->getResource();
$Result = $Statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$Statement->closeCursor();
```

Thank you  Ukuser32 for supporting me to find solution

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)